# How to figure out why file is missing when trying to Run Configurations (set an Argument in Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Error Message]

Hello everyone, Java beginner here. I am trying to run some java code in eclipse IDE, and set my args x = 25 from
Run > Run Configurations > Arguments > Apply > Run. However, before I can get to Arguments, I get this error message (see photo below). Does anyone know what this means or why I am getting this? What does this specific '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core' do?

**MY CODE BELOW:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class IOTest {
    
    public IOTest () {
        
    }
    
    public void readFile () {
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader("movies.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
            
            String line = br.readLine();
            
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            
            br.close();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load file.");
        }
    }
    
    public void writeFile () {
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("tvshows.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(file);
            
            bw.write("Seinfeld\n");
            bw.write("Breaking Bad\n");
            bw.write("The Simpsons\n");
            bw.write("Family Guy\n");
            
            bw.close();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load/create file.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IOTest test = new IOTest();
        test.readFile();
        test.writeFile();
        
        if (args.length == 1) {
            // Do something.
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
        } else {
            // Do something else.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core" is the location in your workspace where Eclipse stores information about the run configuration. Eclipse should have created this automatically.

Comment: Note if you are looking at the workspace using Finder it defaults to hiding names starting with '.' Use Command+Shift+. to turn on showing these files/folders.